# where is theme settings in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: themes, settings, 18.04

I have just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. My installed theme was Flatabulous. My desktop looks really weird. 
I can not find theme settings in System Settings. 
Have is it been removed? How am I supposed to change theme and icons?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a number of Theme apps that are not installed by default.  You can list them by hitting the **All Applications** button at the bottom of the Launch Panel, and typing `theme`.

The list includes:

- **Themes** - Manage themes to change how your desktop looks
- **Appearance** - Change the background and the theme
- **Gnome Tweaks** - Tweak advance Gnome 3 settings
- **Customize Look and Feel** - Customize look and feel of your desktop and applications.

When you type in the **All Applications** menu it searches your installed application as well as the repository for matches.

**The most common and effective tool is `gnome-tweaks`**

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```